# how to create a HTML file on the client's system using webservice (RESTful)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest

Is it possible to create an HTML file on the client's system when the client invokes the RESTful service? The contents of the HTML file is passed as input to the service.

```
public void GetHTML(string ID, string serviceName, string description)
{
    string content = description;
    string filename = "id_" + ID.Trim();
    string location = @"C:\sd\files\" + filename + ".html";
    FileStream file = 
       new FileStream( location, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    file.Close();
    File.WriteAllText(location, content);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're actually trying to do? Try to include the processes you're taking and what your expected output/outcome is. Your question appears quite broad.

Comment: So I have a method which takes the content as the argument and the output is an HTML file. And the file should be saved on the client's system

Comment: The answer is yes. However, I doubt that really helps you. Care to elaborate on your question?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check.

Comment: The above code works fine if invoked on localhost. And then I hosted the webservice on MS Azure and invoked it, but gives an error.

Comment: @FeistyMango - normally answer to "can I create file on client machine by some code on server" is "no"... Could you please comment on your approach where you can do so?

Comment: I interpreted "create an html file on the client's system" as streaming a file response back from the server. That is a pretty common operation. I could have been mistaken in what he meant since this post has been edited and commented on further since I made my comment.